# Disallow line breaks in long Row

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I'm displaying a long row of images with a horizontal scrollbar that should make the images 'go off the screen' to the left or right, instead of wrapping to display all the images on multiple lines.

```
images = Table[
   ExampleData[RandomChoice[ExampleData["TestImage"]]], {i, 30}];
Pane[Row[images], Scrollbars -> {True, False}]
```

I don't know how to force the layout engine to not wrap the elements of the  array.  Appending `SpanFromLeft` or other spanning restrictions to each element doesn't work.  `LineBreakWithin -> False` would seem to be the easiest solution, but it doesn't work, and isn't 'fully integrated' into the language and 'subject to change'.  Perhaps some setting of `LinebreakAdjustments` would do it, but it probably fails for the same reason `LineBreakWithin` does.

How can I tell `Row` to have an infinite page width and not wrap while formatting so that `Pane` can just scroll one longer-than-screen width row of images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pane[Style[Row[images], LineBreakWithin -> False, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {.5, .5}], 
  Scrollbars -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

```
Pane[Style[Row[images], LineBreakWithin -> False, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {.5, .5}], 
 Scrollbars -> {True, False}, ImageSize -> {700, 200}, ScrollPosition -> {300, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: So that the `Pane` doesn't become wider than the screen, but also has an appropriate width limit, `ImageSize -> {UpTo[CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize][[1]] - 100], UpTo[9999]}` is useful

Comment: Two comments. You can use `ImageSize -> Full` or `ImageSize -> Scaled[1]` to default to WindowSize, and you can use `BaseStyle->{LineBreakWithin->False}` as an option to Pane instead of using `LineBreakWithin -> False` as an option to Style.

Comment: @CarlWoll  Perfect! Thanks